# IBM JVM and proxy parameters

Tags: java, proxy, jvm

with Oracle JVM I use

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xx -Dhttp.proxyUser=xxx -Dhttp.proxyPassword=xxx -jar myApp.jar
```

to start my applicaiton which is behind a firefall. Unfortunately this does not work on IBM JVM on SUSE Enterprise. I get always java.lang.Exception: 407 Proxy Authorization Requiered. How can I declare proxy user and password on IBM JVM?

Comment: Either your `myApp.jar` use the property `http.proxyPassword` for the authentication or with the Oracle JVM you use a proxy which do not require an authentication and the property is simple not used. `http.proxyPassword` is not a standard JVM property regarding [Networking Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html). If the proxy is a socks proxy you might use the property `java.net.socks.password`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesn't work with java.net.socks.password, so i download oracle jvm. Maybe you change your comment to answer so we can close this question.

Comment: I don't believe that using the Oracle JVM will solve it. As the property `-Dhttp.proxyPassword` is not mentioned in the documentation the problem might still exist.